# Не удается вывести данные в Tableview из массива

Tags: массивы, swift, uitableview

Делаю парсинг html-таблицы, разбиваю на классы, но вывести эти данные в Tableview никак не получается. Не обнаруживается ни одна переменная.
Ссылка на git: https://github.com/golub1/timetable1-master2

Comment: При удачном парсе, объект класса можете распечатать? Как вы выводите данные в таблицу? В коде не вижу dataSour'сов

Comment: если я делаю печать из этой части кода, то да
defaul: 
break
}
self.shedule.appenbd(timetable)
print(timetable.zamen)
}

Comment: Запушил изменения, прошу прощения

Comment: Откуда у вашего класса свойство count ? "return ScheduleItem.count" надо возвращать количество элементов в массиве "schedule.count"

Comment: поправил, если использую cell?.testLabel?.test = timetable.zamen[IndexPath.row], то падает ошибка. Может конвертация данных нужна?

Comment: Вы немного не понимаете ситуацию с жизнью объектов, timetable это переменная во viewDidLoad, и метод tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) --> UITableViewCell его не видит. У вас есть ваш массив schedule, и надо данные брать из него. Для этого надо возвращать объект из этого массива. schedule[indexPath.row].zamen

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно. Я просто запутался в переменных. Большое спасибо! Ответьте на мой вопрос и я отмечу его. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return //колличество этоментов в массиве
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell



        cell?.textLabel?.text = //элемент массива (и его своства)
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо еще раз

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, но если я делаю print(schedule[IndexPath.row].zamen), то получаю пустой ответ, в следствии чего и в tableview ничего нет

Comment: Значит значения не парсятся в массив, проверяйте ваш парсер! Распечатайте schedule[IndexPath.row] прямо в методе DataSource что он распечатает?

Comment: Правильно вас понял, так?
   print(schedule[indexPath.row])
      //  print(self.schedule[indexPath.row].zamen)
        cell.textLabel?.text = schedule[indexPath.row].zamen

Comment: Распечатайте schedule, после парса. Весь массив. Помоему у вас парс вообще не работает.

Comment: решено, нашел ошибку в коде, опечатка:)